# Tableheaderview in iOS8 not showing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8

```
self.channelStarter = [[ChannelStarter alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.tv.frame.size.width, 44)];
self.tv.tableHeaderView = self.channelStarter;

po self.tv.talbeHeaderView
<ChannelStarter: 0x7fd0c1d6e420; frame = (0 0; 414 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd0c1d49ee0>>

//ChannelStarter.m
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    return self;
}
```

I don't see the yellow background, just my tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implement method initWithFrame:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
       if(self) {
          self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
         }
    return self;
}
```